# Dragging full-width elements - possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am building simple slider with dragging ability. For now, I use `pageX` to determine the position, like so:

```
var dragdir = 0,
    drag = null;
$('article.small-section').on('mousedown', function(ev) {
    drag = 1;
    dragdir = ev.pageX;
    if(drag) {
        $(this).css('cursor','move');
    }
}).on('mouseup', function(e){
    drag = null
    if(!drag) {
        $(this).css('cursor','initial');
        $(this).css('left','0')
    }
});

$('article.small-section').on('mousemove', function(e) {
    if(drag) {
        if(dragdir > e.pageX) {
            //console.log(dragdir+'|'+e.pageX)
            if(dragdir > e.pageX+100) {
                $(this).parent('section').cycle('prev');
            }
            $(this).css('right','');
            $(this).css('left','-'+(parseInt(e.pageX/10))+'px');
        } else {
            if(dragdir < e.pageX-100) {
                $(this).parent('section').cycle('next');
            }
            $(this).css('left','');
            $(this).css('right','-'+(parseInt(e.pageX/10))+'px');
        }

    }
});
```

It works great dragging to the right. To the left - it does, then it backs (or doesn't go at all). I noticed that `pageX` is going down - that's the problem. How can I fix it?

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2jEJH/1/

Comment: there are undefined errors in your fiddle. Why aren't you using jquery draggable?

Comment: Fixed (errors caused by the missing plugin, not needed here). I don't want to bring whole jQUI for this one element.

Comment: Just bring draggable/droppable and the core elements required for it?

Comment: 40KBs, it's my last resort, since I aim for as much lightweight stuff as I can.